# Mac shortcut : switch between apps in the same virtual desktop

Tags: macos, applications, shortcut, desktop

I want to switch between only two application with a shortcut in a virtual desktop.

Example : only switch between google chrome and apple music (only this two apps are in the virtual desktop).

I want to switch automatically between this two apps, regardless if I have other apps in other virtual desktop.

My problem, all shortcut I found not works correctly for my problem.

cmd + tab (two apps but if I focus on a third apps in other desktop, it's not working anymore)

cmd + ` (only same app)

ctrl + f4 (if more than my two apps, it's go foreach apps in all virtual desktop)

In fact, I would like to switch only between apps which are in the same virtual desktop.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Aurelien did you have any luck? I would like to do something similar myself